# Запуск php приложения в связке nginx-apache-php в докере

Tags: docker, php-nginx

Есть докер-образ на базе php-fpm, внутри php-приложение и фронт-статика всякая...

Необходимо запустить это в связке с nginx

Но, т.к. там есть .htaccess с инструкциями apache, то нужен еще и apache.

Есть опыт развертывания подобной связки, когда скрипты и статика лежат на хост-машине и монтируются в контейнеры nginx, apache и php.

Но сейчас все скрипты лежат внутри контейнера и я не знаю как их подмонтировать в nginx и apache.

Есть еще вариант сделать один контейнер, в котором будет и nginx и apache и php, но, говорят, это не очень хороший подход.

Вопрос: как это можно все поднять?

P.S. Еще вариант копировать скрипты и статику в общую папку на хост-машине перед стартом контейнера и ее монтировать к остальным контейнерам, но это похоже на костыль...

UPD.1 Нашел вариант решения через один контейнер
https://github.com/TrafeX/docker-php-nginx
Пробую...

Comment: во втором контейнере будет у вас nginx, который проксируется на apache

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, А как nginx будет отдавать статику? она в другом контейнере

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш образ базируется на `php:<version>-apache` то в этом образе уже есть Apache webserver. См. https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Если нет, то директивы .htaccess легко преобразовать в директивы nginx. См. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html